# ss but not sz for eszett

Tags: eszett

If I'm not mistaken, ss is an alternative to ß. Why is sz not
an alternative?  The ß seems to be nothing but an antiqua-like representation
of the sz-ligature in Fraktur, and so one should expect the
alternative to be sz.

Comment: But you are mistaken. Suisse-German has no ß. They always use ss. In German German, there has been a writing reform. Since then, you use ss for short vocals, and ß for long ones ("Die Straße des Hasses.") but you can't choose between them. Before the reform, it wasn't that consistent. For Austrian German I'm not informed, but they have a ß, that's sure.

Comment: “Unfall der Rechtschreibgeschichte”. Both, _ss_ and _sz_ (or rather _ſs_ and _ſz_ or _ſʒ_), have been possible replacements and origins of _ß_. Wherever the 21st-century orthographic rules still require _ß_, historically _sz_ would have been preferred, but meanwhile almost everyone and especially the Swiss had already settled on a single replacement, which almost always was _ss_. While doubling of letters is a feature of German graphotactics it has in common with many others, _sz_ would be a rather unusual digraph (despite Czech), but _ſz_ matches _tz_ – _ch/ck_ would suggest _cs/cſ_ instead!

Comment: Sz does exist in the loan words *Szene* and *Szintillation* and German speakers pronounce it as a sharp s. (About unusual digraphs common in German: **pf**)

Comment: @Janka ["Szene"](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Szene) is pronounced /ˈstseːnə/, not /ˈseːnə/.

Comment: Which dialect? I don't know people who pronouce a ts in Szene. Seems like an overcorrection to me.

Comment: @Janka Standard pronunciation (for the meanings 1, 2, 3, 6, 7 of the linked Wiktionary article). In expressions like "Szenekneipe" or "Drogenszene" (meanings 4, 5 of the linked Wiktionary article), /ˈseːnə/ seems to be common, though.

Answer (score 0):

The Fraktur typeset had ſʒ, but it simply never made it into Antiqua. See

https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%9F#Historischer_Vergleich_als_Tabelle